# How to build twitter's elephant-bird for thrift 0.9.1?

Tags: maven, hadoop, twitter, thrift, elephantbird

The README file for [elephant-bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird) mentions:

> Thrift 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, greater versions than 0.9 are provided via thrift9 maven profile

I am using `mvn package -e -Dprotobuf.version=2.6.1 -Dthrift.version=0.9.1` but it gives me the error:

```
.
.
.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/user/Downloads/elephant-bird-elephant-bird-4.13/core/thrift7/src/test/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/TestThrift7BinaryProtocol.java:[24,12] error: cannot find symbol
.
.
.
```

Have I must install thrift 0.7.0 to get it working or is there some way that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

protobuf version : **2.5.0** and thrift version : **0.9.0** worked for me

```
mvn package -Dprotobuf.version=2.5.0 -Dthrift.version=0.9.0
```